# Is there a way to ensure that a device connected to a serial port which appears in registry is ready to be used?

Tags: c++, windows, serial-port, device-driver

I use a function which runs periodically and gets serial ports list using functions SetupDiEnumDeviceInfo and SetupDiOpenDevRegKey.

Code can be found here:
https://github.com/wjwwood/serial/blob/master/src/impl/list_ports/list_ports_win.cc

Sometimes when I connect a device and I try to open a port that appears in the list (e.g. COM3) in order to use it, I get the error: "Specified port does not exist". This may happen once or twice and then I am able to open the port and use the device normally.

I was thinking that maybe the device connected to the port is not ready to be used first time I try to use it (maybe doing some configuration or something else) and if there is a way to ensure that the port which appears in the list and has the device connected is ready to be used.

I should also mention that I give the full device path. If 'COM3' is the device, then I specify "\.\COM3".

Comment: You'll have to deal with the fundamental limitation that serial ports are legacy devices that don't support Plug & Play.  There is no device arrival notification for them.  So you'll have to tap your foot while the underlying USB or Bluetooth device driver initializes itself, it can take several seconds.  You of course know when it is done, CreateFile() no longer fails :)

Comment: Finding the COM number is an unnecessary step.  The `SetupDi` family of functions directly give you a device interface instance path, which is a valid argument to `CreateFile`.  Then you don't have to worry whether the DOS device alias COM-whatever has been initialized yet.

Comment: Could you please provide an example of finding a device interface instance path?

Comment: I managed to find the device interface instance path, but it seems that device interface instance path appears in registry before COM port does, so I don't think that this can help me solve the "Specified port does not exit problem". Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are doing it wrong (i.e. reading the registry is not a good/correct way to detect USB devices).

I had this problem (detecting a particular MP3 player brand being connected to USB) about three years ago and ended up using WMI. There is a [C++ sample application](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowshardware/USBView-sample-application-e3241039) that exemplifies this.

WMI will allow you to use WQL (similar to SQL) to query devices, then filter results and identify your interesting devices.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have found [this](http://naughter.com/enumser.html) software which enumerates serial ports with 9 different ways and has one that uses WMI. I used the tool to enumerate COM ports in my computer but there is no difference between the ports that WMI function and UsingSetupAPI1 function(the one that I use)return.